# Transaction failed during the createPool UniswapV3 function execution on Goerli network

Tags: transactions, ethers.js, uniswapv3, factory, ethsigner

I'm trying to call CreatePool function from UniswapV3Factory on Goerli newtork using Infura node, so i passed two ERC20 tokens with 0.3 fee  existed in the network as input parameters and that dosen't have Pool, but an error encountered during factory contract execution.

Transaction Hash: 0xa4957038fbea08565ed7ceae443f2ff7f096a076eb516e96ce6cba118ca98644

Code implemented:

```
import { ethers } from 'ethers'
import { abi as IUniswapV3FactoryABI } from '@uniswap/v3-core/artifacts/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV3Factory.sol/IUniswapV3Factory.json'


const providerTestnet = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(env.Infura_key)
const factoryAddress = '0x1F98431c8aD98523631AE4a59f267346ea31F984'
const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(env.private_key, providerTestnet);

const factoryContract = new ethers.Contract(factoryAddress, IUniswapV3FactoryABI, wallet)
async function createPool() {
    const POOL_FEE = 3000;
factoryContract.createPool("0x7af963cf6d228e564e2a0aa0ddbf06210b38615d","0x509Ee0d083DdF8AC028f2a56731412edD63223B9",POOL_FEE, {
    gasLimit: 100000
  });

}

createPool().then((result) => {
    console.log(result)
  })
```

Comment: Thank you for that small tidbit of information. I was trying to figure out how to import the ABI for the Factory Contract.